# Swift: mudar botão de lugar de acordo com o aparecimento do teclado

Tags: swift, xcode, teclado

Estou fazendo um aplicativo no Xcode e gostaria que o botão, que fica na parte inferior da tela, se movimentasse de acordo com aparecimento do teclado.

Obrigado

[image: Tela do Aplicativo]

[image: Tela do Aplicativo]

Answer (score 2):

Quando o teclado é exibido ou inibido, você pode escutar notificações para processá-las. No seu view controller, inscreva-se para ouvir esses eventos da seguinte forma:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow , object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidHide), name: .UIKeyboardDidHide , object: nil)
}
```

Você também deve criar as funções que vocês está informando no `selector`:

```
@objc private func keyboardDidShow() {
    // Processe aqui para quando o teclado terminar de ser *exibido*
}

@objc private func keyboardDidHide() {
    // Processe aqui para quando o teclado terminar de ser *inibido*
}
```

Existem quatro eventos desse tipo para o teclado:

- `.UIKeyboardWillShow`;
- `.UIKeyboardDidShow`;
- `.UIKeyboardWillHide`;
- `.UIKeyboardDidHide`.

Você pode assinar qualquer um deles para ouvir as mudanças relacionadas ao teclado.

Uma lista maior de eventos relacionados à sua aplicação pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow?language=objc).